# how can I close all my form and return to my login form?

Tags: c#

I want to close all my form by using `Applicaton.Exit()` method but it will exit everything and it will not return to my login form. I want also that if my parent form will be close , the child form will be close too .

Any help will be appreciated and thank you very much .

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of answers to this question. It depends on your situation, I have used `Application.Restart()` in a software I made and it worked fine, because I did not had any code for closing events or any code that prevented my application from shutting down. So you can simply use this:

```
Application.Restart();
```

You may also add `Environment.Exit(0);` to the above code which may prevent any closing event handlers to be fired.

#### Alternative Way:

You may also use this:

```
Process.Start(Application.ExecutablePath);
this.Close();
```

Do not forget

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```